# How can I give an imported library access to current global variables?

Tags: python, import

Let's say I have two python files

a.py

```
x = "hello world"
import b
```

b.py

```
print x
```

I want to run a.py, which 1st creates the 'x' variable, and then I want to print the 'x' variable by importing b.

Basically I want to have all of the code in b.py run in a.py as if the source code of b were part of the source code of a. Is there any way to achieve this behavior in python?

Comment: I think these examples are possibly a little bit *too* minimal for people to understand what you're trying to achieve. You say that you're "working with someone else's code"- does that mean that you don't have control over the contents of `b.py`?

Comment: Marius, that is correct, I have their source file. I could possibly turn everything in that source file into an function and provide that function with the arguments it needs. Still, I was wondering if there was a way to just have file b access file a's variables.

Comment: In that case, at the top of `b.py`, you could add `from a import *`, to import all variables into `b`'s global namespace. This isn't recommended generally, but it does sound a bit like `b.py` isn't necessarily following best practices so maybe it's OK.

Comment: Brilliant! That did the trick. I was afraid of an infinite regress of imports but that did not happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Don't***

Instead use functions:

in b.py

```
def do_something(x):
    print x
```

in a.py

```
import b
x = "Hello World"
b.do_something(x)
```

You can do other things, but you'll find everything works better if you do all your work in functions and avoid global variables.

Alternately, for advanced uses you can do:

```
variables = {
   'x' : 'Hello World'
}

with open('b.py') as b_file:
     exec b_file in variables
```

Comment: Winston, thanks for the suggestion. I'm working with someone else's code and unfortunately it's a mess; putting everything into a function would require a ton of arguments. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: @kyphos, ah. Too often newcomers want to do this for the wrong reason. It looks like somebody pointed out a way in the comments on the question. I've added an alternate approach to my answer.